# How to pass page number to pageClick function in Jquery-Simple pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination, jquery-pagination

I am using jquery simplePagination.js in my application. I created a function name showProjectPage(pageNumber). It is used to show the particular page with the page number. I used the following code for doing pagination using SimplePagination.js

```
$(".paging").pagination({
    items: totalItmes,
    itemsOnPage: perPageItem,
    cssStyle: 'light-theme',
    currentPage : currentPageNumber,
    onPageClick : showProjectPage
});
```

I can call the function usning **onPageClick : showProjectPage**.
How can I pass the pageNumber to this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
onPageClick : function(){
            showProjectPage(currentPageNumber)
          }
```

**Full Code**

```
$(".paging").pagination({
    items: totalItmes,
    itemsOnPage: perPageItem,
    cssStyle: 'light-theme',
    currentPage : currentPageNumber,        
    onPageClick : function(){
            showProjectPage(currentPageNumber)
          }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that answer is incorrect. It needs to be:

```
 onPageClick : function(pageNum) {
             showProjectPage(pageNum) ;
        }
```

That works for me, anyway.